# Initial Azure VM setup won't allow any port connections (NSG port allowed VM firewall off)

Tags: sql-server, azure, networking, port

I've created a new Azure VM and tried opening 1433 for a remote database connection (I understand long term this shouldn't be a public port).

I've created a rule in my NSG to open port 1433, and entirely disabled windows firewall, and I still cannot get through port 1433.

**If I go in and disassociate the NSG, then I can connect just fine, so it's not the server that's blocking, it's happening at the NSG level**

This is a fresh install of Windows 2012 R2 Datacenter.

Here's my NSG

[Inbound security rules image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHsFD.png)

Here's my VM Networking details

[Networking VM Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NPpp.png)

Comment: do you have something listening on 1433

Comment: if you are trying to connect via a corporate network you will need to ensure outbound 1433 is open.  Most corpnets block 1433 to public endpoints after the slammer worm in 2003.

Comment: Not a corporate network and even services like canyouseemee cannt connect.

Comment: It seems there is nothing wrong with the NSGin your picture and if there is another NSG associated with your subnet? also if you add the rule in your load balancer for your VM?

Answer (score 0):

Check if SQL-Server service accept remote connections and if it's listening on 1433 port. Specify a source IP address for the rule (is absolutely not recommended to open a port to all). Do a port scan to the specific ip.